# Too much data in Contains (Linq): How to increase performace

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, linq

I have a linq query like this:

```
from a in context.table_A
   join b in
   (from temp in context.table_B
   where idlist.Contains(temp.id)
   select temp)
   on a.seq_id equals b.seq_id into c
   where
   idlist.Contains(a.id)
   select new MyObject
   {
     ...
   }).ToList();
```

- idlist is List
- The problem I have is that the idlist has too many values (hundreds of thousands to several million records). It works fine with few records but when there are too many records, the contains function is error.

Error log is

> The query plan cannot be created due to lack of internal resources of
> the query processor. This is a rare event and only occurs for very
> complex queries or queries that reference a very large number of
> tables or partitions. Make the query easy.

I want to improve the performance of this section. Any ideas?

Comment: Try to check in batches.

Comment: what is the soruce of `idlist`?

Comment: idlist is parameter of this function

Comment: Can you reverse the query and join _to_ the IdList rather than from it? 
Alternatively restructure your data so that your references can be looked up in one query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest to install extension [linq2db.EntityFrameworkCore](https://github.com/linq2db/linq2db.EntityFrameworkCore) and use temporary tables with fast BulkCopy

```
public class IdItem
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
}

...

var items = idList.Select(id => new IdItem { Id = id });

using var db = context.CreateLinqToDBConnection();
using var temp = db.CreateTempTable("#IdList", items);

var query =
   from a in context.table_A
   join id1 in temp on a.Id equals id1.Id
   join b in context.table_B on a.seq_id equals b.seq_id
   join id2 in temp on b.Id equals id2.Id
   select new MyObject
   {
      ...
   };

// switch to alternative translator
var query = query.ToLinqToDB();

var result = query.ToList();
```